# Key Hashes facebook api

Tags: android, facebook-api

Делаю приложение, в котором нужно подключить facebook sdk. При этом facebook dev console у заказчика, и он просит cгенерированный hash. Безопасно ли передавать ему его, не будет ли каких-то последствий? И за что этот хэш вообще отвечает?

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости речь идёт о хеше ключа для подписи приложения. Это вполне безопасно, так как алгоритм `sha1`, который в этом случае используется для получения хеша, является необратимым. То есть обратно ваш ключ из хеша не получить.

А используется хеш для того, чтобы facebook удостоверился, что именно вы подписали приложение, которое к нему обращается. Если кто-то разберёт ваше приложение, изменит и подпишет своим ключём, то facebook уже не даст этому приложению доступ к своему API.